# C# Show Class Library from another Project

Tags: c#, winforms, class-library, control-library

Here are the steps I have used to create the winforms Project OneB
Using Visual Studio 2019 with Net 4.8 I created OneB
Then I created a Windows Forms Class Library named CLP.
Opened OneB and Added Existing Project CLP and then Added Reference to CLP.
Here is the code in OneB **The issue is with this line of code `form.Show();`**

```cs
namespace OneB
{
    public partial class frmStart : Form
    {
        string SS;

        public frmStart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btnShowLib_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SS = "HI we are from OneB";
            var form = new CLP.Form1();
            form.UdpateTextBoxWith(SS);
            form.Show();
        }
    }
```

Now the code in CLP the Class Library
This code references a textbox1 BUT the project has no Form that the textbox1 can live on.

```cs
namespace CLP
{

    public class Form1
        {
        private object textbox1;
        private object newText;

        public object SS { get; private set; }

        public void UdpateTextBoxWith(string v)
            {
                newText = SS;
                textbox1 = newText;
            }
        public void Show()
        {
            // This is intelesense suggestion YEP it throws
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**OK Number of Issues here

How do I call the Class Library ?**

**With NO form to show the textox1 text change should I be using a Control Library ?**

This is just a test project my final goal is to use a Library Class or Control Library to
call CRUD methods for a SQLite DB
Side NOTE I made this change from 5 to 4.8 in both projects

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
</startup>
```

Comment: It looks like you just added a class and named it `Form1` and expected it to work as a form. Forms have to inherit the `Form` class which provides a lot of base functionality for them. Get rid of your class and actually add a Windows Form, just as you would in an application project. I don't think you should have to create a Control Library project for that. i think the only difference is a Class Library adds a simple class by default while a Control Library adds a user control.

Comment: @jmcilhinney OK I can make it work with a Form added but now the Class Library is codeless and does Nothing so I am not sure this Class Library is even need with this design Not what I had in mind

Comment: How can it be codeless if it has a form in it? A form is a class so it has all the code associated with that class. If you expect to be able to update a `TextBox` then you need to add a `TextBox` to that form. I don't see why you're trying to treat this form differently to every other form you've ever used. The fact that it's in a library project rather than an application project is irrelevant. Treat it like every other form.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I stand corrected YES I do need the Class Library and the form need to be part of the Class Library When I said codeless the form I added looked like it was not part of the Class Library. I deleted the Class Library and learned my lesson NEVER doubt JMC are you still in Hawaii ? My Best